# Eclipse Crashes When Auto Complete is Used - Java Error Log is EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm

Eclipse was working fine until today. Every time the autocomplete menu pops up, Eclipse crashes and a Java error log file is created which I have pasted below. For example, if I'm writing the name of a variable and press control + space, it crashes after the autocomplete menu pops up. Everything else other than the autocomplete seems to work fine.

I read some things that it may be related to the web browser of Eclipse and I noticed that when I go to Eclipse settings and click on the web browser settings, Eclipse also crashes so I am thinking it has something to do with that. Another thing to note is that when reinstalling Eclipse, the Eclipse installer also crashes with the same Java error so I had to reinstall using a package.

Things I have tried:

New install of Eclipse.

New install of the Java JDK, tried different JDK versions as well.

Turned off Antir-virus, no change.

**I am using latest version of Windows 10 64 bit (my windows install is pretty fresh btw, made a clean install a couple of weeks ago). Latest version of Eclipse. Tried various versions of the JDK.**

**Here is the top half and the last half of the log file. Was not able to post all of the log file. Can post more of it if needed.**

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffb6b65bdc8, pid=12156, tid=12520
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (12.0.2+10) (build 12.0.2+10)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (12.0.2+10, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [mshtml.dll+0x8dbdc8]
#
# No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  S U M M A R Y ------------

Command Line: -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8 -Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UseStringDeduplication --add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8 -Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true -Xms256m -Xmx1024m --add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM 

Host: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU         950  @ 3.07GHz, 8 cores, 8G,  Windows 10 , 64 bit Build 18362 (10.0.18362.329)
Time: Tue Oct  1 21:36:45 2019 Eastern Daylight Time elapsed time: 24 seconds (0d 0h 0m 24s)

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8 -Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UseStringDeduplication --add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8 -Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true -Xms256m -Xmx1024m --add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM 
java_command: <unknown>
java_class_path (initial): C:\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.500.v20190715-1310.jar
Launcher Type: generic

[Global flags]
     intx CICompilerCount                          = 4                                         {product} {ergonomic}
     uint ConcGCThreads                            = 2                                         {product} {ergonomic}
     uint G1ConcRefinementThreads                  = 8                                         {product} {ergonomic}
   size_t G1HeapRegionSize                         = 1048576                                   {product} {ergonomic}
    uintx GCDrainStackTargetSize                   = 64                                        {product} {ergonomic}
   size_t InitialHeapSize                          = 268435456                                 {product} {command line}
   size_t MarkStackSize                            = 4194304                                   {product} {ergonomic}
   size_t MaxHeapSize                              = 1073741824                                {product} {command line}
   size_t MaxNewSize                               = 643825664                                 {product} {ergonomic}
   size_t MinHeapDeltaBytes                        = 1048576                                   {product} {ergonomic}
    uintx NonNMethodCodeHeapSize                   = 5836300                                {pd product} {ergonomic}
    uintx NonProfiledCodeHeapSize                  = 122910970                              {pd product} {ergonomic}
    uintx ProfiledCodeHeapSize                     = 122910970                              {pd product} {ergonomic}
    uintx ReservedCodeCacheSize                    = 251658240                              {pd product} {ergonomic}
     bool SegmentedCodeCache                       = true                                      {product} {ergonomic}
     bool UseCompressedClassPointers               = true                                 {lp64_product} {ergonomic}
     bool UseCompressedOops                        = true                                 {lp64_product} {ergonomic}
     bool UseG1GC                                  = true                                      {product} {command line}
     bool UseLargePagesIndividualAllocation        = false                                  {pd product} {ergonomic}
     bool UseStringDeduplication                   = true                                      {product} {command line}
---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 10 , 64 bit Build 18362 (10.0.18362.329)

CPU:total 8 (initial active 8) (4 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 26 stepping 5, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, ht, tsc, tscinvbit, tscinv

Memory: 4k page, system-wide physical 9207M (2309M free)
TotalPageFile size 18423M (AvailPageFile size 5348M)
current process WorkingSet (physical memory assigned to process): 436M, peak: 449M
current process commit charge ("private bytes"): 531M, peak: 548M

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (12.0.2+10) for windows-amd64 JRE (12.0.2+10), built on Jul 16 2019 01:56:17 by "mach5one" with MS VC++ 15.5 (VS2017)

END.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future readers, the issue was caused by a dying hard drive. A new HDD and a fresh install fixed the issues.